# issues in install phpunit - Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, xampp

I am getting this error while i try to install phpunit in xampp.

```
C:\xampp\php>pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
Attempting to discover channel "phpunit"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "phpunit"...
unknown channel "phpunit" in "phpunit/PHPUnit"
invalid package name/package file "phpunit/PHPUnit"
install failed
```

Comment: "End of Life for PEAR Installation Method"....
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method

Answer (score 11):

You need to do a

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
```

before issuing the install command.

---

Apart from that note that xampp usually ships with a old (broken) version of pear.

Please make sure you have the current version installed with `pear version`. It should say 1.9.4.

If not don't try to upgrade the pear that xampp ships. While it is possible with much effort it is a lot easier to install a clean, fresh pear instead of fixing the broken stuff.

See: [Pear Installation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php)

Comment: ```pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de``` does not change anything for me

Comment: !!!!! PHP UNIT NO LONGER SUPPORTS PEAR INSTALLATION !!!!! see http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

Comment: It looks like pear.phpunit.de channel is not working anymore - receive 401 HTTP code "Gone"

Answer (score 1):

You can not install phpunit through PEAR any more, as @aaronbauman mentioned. You can not install it with apt-get, because PHPCoverage is not included in the PHPUnit package. Instead you should download phar file:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar

chmod +x phpunit.phar

sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit

phpunit --version
```

Documentation: https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is supposed to work for PHPUnit. It may be that you are using a proxy that doesn't support HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this with using `pear.phpunit.de` instead of `phpunit`

```
# pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
# pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
# pear install --alldeps symfony2/Yaml
# pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 0):

`pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit` worked for me