# cannot install pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium

Tags: selenium, phpunit, pear

I am trying to install `PHPUnit_Selenium` using the command

`pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium`

The version of pear that i am running is 1.9.4. The above command returned

> Attempting to discover channel "phpunit"...
>   Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "phpunit"...
>   unknown channel "phpunit" in "phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium"
>   invalid package name/package file "phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium"
>   install failed

Searching google I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667994/issues-in-install-phpunit-attempting-fallback-to-https-instead-of-http-on-chan) (a few times) as a suggestion. So I tried

`pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de`

and

`sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de` (incase it made a difference)

previous command returned

> Discovering channel pear.phpunit.de over http:// failed with message: channel-add: Cannot open "http://pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml" (File http://pear.phpunit.de:80/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  )
>   ))
>   Trying to discover channel pear.phpunit.de over https:// instead
>   Discovery of channel "pear.phpunit.de" failed (channel-add: Cannot open "https://pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml" (Connection to `pear.phpunit.de:443' failed: Operation timed out))

What do I need to do to install PHPUnit_Selenium?

Comment: You might also need to ensure you have the proper access (Administrator on Windows, sudo with *nix).  Ensure the web is connected.  Also, use the --all-deps to include additional dependencies in case you are missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to specify a proxy for pear to route it's traffic through. Try something like:

```
$ sudo pear config-set http_proxy http://foo.bar/
$ sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
$ sudo pear install phpunit/PHP_Selenium
```

Answer (score 5):

The PEAR channel for phpunit has been [discontinued](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1229#issuecomment-40899737) as of the end of April 2014, to install PHPUnit and PHPUnit_Selenium install via composer.

Configure your composer.json to the specific package version (See [PHPUnit_Selenium](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit-selenium))

In your `composer.json` file, write:

`{
        "require": {
                "phpunit/phpunit": "*",
                "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.3.3"
        }
}`

Try the following command:
`$ composer install`

Answer (score 3):

Use "pear.phpunit.de" instead of "phpunit"

```
sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Selenium
```

Phpunit require curl to be installed,if you didn't install it try this:

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: When I try that command I get 
`Attempting to discover channel "pear.phpunit.de"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "pear.phpunit.de"...
unknown channel "pear.phpunit.de" in "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Selenium"
invalid package name/package file "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Selenium"
install failed`. I defiantly have curl installed. I found an alternative route and installed it using Composer

Answer (score 0):

Installing phpunit-selenium package in Ubuntu Trusty is as easy as running:

```
apt-get install phpunit-selenium
```