# pear install phpunit/PHP_Selenium not finding selenium package

Tags: selenium, yii, phpunit

I am new for TDD and following "Agile Web application Development with yii" book. I have successfully installed phpunit and trying to install selenium extension as book recommends. But when i try to install phpunit_selenim, it gives me following error:

```
No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Selenium" install failed
```

I have tried to do the installation process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686355/cannot-install-pear-install-phpunit-phpunit-selenium), but it did not help, i got the same result. is there anything i missed up or there is another way to install it?

P.S. I am using ubuntu with lamp server to develop yii application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't add comment, so before Sergey's answer do:

```
sudo pear install phpunit
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
```

After, Sergey's:

```
pear clear-cache
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install PHPUnit/PHPUnit_Selenium
```

This work for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try next sequence of commands:

```
pear clear-cache
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install PHPUnit/PHPUnit_Selenium
```

(Also looks like it was attempt to install PHP_Selenium instead of PHPUnit_Selenium package according to your error message)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this also didn't work. It gave me `No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Selenium"
install failed` error.